# Função para adicionar elementos array Multidimensional

Tags: php

Sou novato no PHP.
Gostaria criar uma função em ao ser chamada incremente um linha no array multidimensional em PHP.
Exemplo:

```
//Array
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Jack', 'ano' => 2002, 'cidade' => 'SÃO PAULO')
);
//Função
function adicionar($nome, $anoNascimento, $cidade){
...
}
//chama função
adicionar("PETER", "2000", "RIBEIRÃO PRETO");

//novo resultado do array
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Jack', 'ano' => 2002, 'cidade' => 'SÃO PAULO'),
    array('name' => 'PETER', 'ano' => 2000, 'cidade' => 'RIBEIRÃO PRETO')
);
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Agradeço desde já

Comment: Você quer criar um array que sirva como "banco de dados"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já existe uma função em PHP que realiza parte dessa tarefa, a `array_push()`. Dê uma lida na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php).

```
//Função

function adiciona($array,$nome,$ano,$cidade){
    $pessoa = array('name' => $nome, 'ano' => $ano, 'cidade' => $cidade);

    array_push($array,$pessoa);

    return $array;
}

//Utilização

$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Jack', 'ano' => 2002, 'cidade' => 'SÃO PAULO')
);

$data = adiciona($data,"PETER", "2000", "RIBEIRÃO PRETO");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Matheus

Answer (score 2):

A outra resposta indicou o `array_push`, mas eu diria que seria melhor (por ser um construtor da linguagem, e não uma função) e mais legível usar o colchetes vazio para adicionar valores.

Exemplo:

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Jack', 'ano' => 2002, 'cidade' => 'SÃO PAULO')
);

$data[] = array('name' => 'Wallace', 'ano' => 1990', 'cidade' => 'Belo Horizonte');
```

A pergunta que eu faria é: Você realmente precisa de uma função para fazer isso? Não seria somente o caso de usar um operador para fazer tal coisa?

Bem, se de fato você precisa, eu utilizaria uma função, porém ao invés de usar o retorno, eu passaria o `array` como referência.

```
$array = [];
$array[] = ['nome' => 'Bacco', 'ano' => 1900, 'cidade' => 'Interior de SP'];

function adicionar(array &$array, $nome, $ano, $cidade) {
     $array[] = compact('nome', 'ano', 'cidade');
}

adicionar($array, 'Wallace', 1990, 'BH');
```

Explicação:

- Ao usar o operador `&`, você não ficará refém do retorno da função e, assim, poderá alterar o valor do `array` de origem diretamente.
- A função `compact` envia as variáveis do escopo atual com os nomes passados por parâmetro para um `array`.
- `array &$array` indica que a variável deve ser do tipo `array` e tem que ser uma variável já existente, que será afetada como referência dentro da função. Para entender um pouco mais, leia sobre [passagem por referência](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php)

Outra curiosidade: No PHP, depois da versão 5.4, você não precisa usar a palavra chave `array()`  para declará-las, você pode usar colchetes...

Exemplo:

```
$data = [
     ['nome' => 'nome', 'valor' => 'valor']
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Você quer criar um array que sirva como "banco de dados"?

Mas, tirando essa pergunta, você, com uma função, que é o que você quer, pode fazer exatamente assim:

```
<?php

//Array
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Jack', 'ano' => 2002, 'cidade' => 'SÃO PAULO')
);

function addNewElement ($nome, $anoNasc, $cidade){
    $GLOBALS['data'][] = ['name' => $nome, 'ano' => $anoNasc, 'cidade' => $cidade]; 

}

addNewElement('Lucas de Carvalho', 1998, 'Rio de Janeiro');

print_r($data);
```

Será impresso:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Jack [ano] => 2002 [cidade] => SÃO PAULO ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Lucas de Carvalho [ano] => 1998 [cidade] => Rio de Janeiro ) )
```